# Django Overriding DateTimeField

Tags: python, django, python-datetime

I currently have a form which allows users to select a datetime, which I display using [a custom bootstrap date picker](https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus/). I have the date shown formatted to MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A.

[image]

The problem is the field doesn't recognize this format. I subclassed models.DateTimeField to convert the formatted date passed in to iso format and save it in the database. I updated my models to use it, but it still says enter a valid date/time.

widgets.py

```
from django.db import models 
from datetime import datetime
import dateparser

class CustomDateTimeField(models.DateTimeField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        compared_date = dateparser.parse(value, date_formats=['%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p'])
        if isinstance(compared_date, datetime):
            return compared_date.isoformat()

        if value is None:
            return value
```

Model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .widgets import CustomDateTimeField 

class Reminder(models.Model):
    remind_types = [('Regular', 'Regular'), ('Long Term', 'Long Term')]
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()  
    remind_time = CustomDateTimeField(blank=True) 
    parent_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    type_of_remind = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=remind_types, default='Regular')
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Forms.py:

```
from bootstrap_modal_forms.forms import BSModalForm
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus import DateTimePickerInput
from .models import Reminder
from django import forms

class NewReminderForm(BSModalForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reminder
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'remind_time', 'type_of_remind']
        widgets = {
            'remind_time': DateTimePickerInput(
                options={"format": "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A"},
                attrs={'placeholder':'Note: If no time is given, there will be no notification'}
            ),
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change DateTime input format in django form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944563/change-datetime-input-format-in-django-form)

Comment: You definitely don't need to override the field.

Comment: Where would I put the input_formats? It doesn't work inside my widgets dict and if I place it in the Form class (like the question has it) the custom datetime picker doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply extend the accepted datetime input formats in `settings.py` like:

```
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS += (
    "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p",
)
```

and keep using the default `models.DateTimeField`