# Displaying datetime field as hours and minutes only (no date displayed) in ModelForm

Tags: python, django

I'm building a calendar on Django. When a user clicks a day on the calendar, he's redirected to a CreateEventForm where he can create an event happening on the day he clicked (selected_date). To save the user the hassle of having to enter the date he selected, I used get_form_kwargs() to send the selected_date to the form and prefill the start_time and end-time fields. In this way, he only needs to enter the hours and minutes for the start_time and end_time of the event.

**My problem**

Currently, the entire "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M" format is displayed like so:

### [image]

I would like to display only the %H:%M. But I want to make sure that the datetime object still contains the date; except that it wouldn't be displayed to the end user, like so:

[image]

I've tried to format the datetime object using form widgets, but it doesn't seem to work. When I format the field to '%H:%M', the field displays like so:

[image]

**Forms**

```
class EventForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Event
    widgets = {
      'start_time': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}, format='%H:%M'),
      'end_time': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'datetime-local'}, format='%H:%M'),
    }
    fields = '__all__'

  def __init__(self, selected_date, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['start_time'].initial = selected_date
    self.fields['end_time'].initial = selected_date
    self.fields['start_time'].input_formats = ('%H:%M',)
    self.fields['end_time'].input_formats = ('%H:%M',)
```

**Models**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('cal:calendar')
```

**Views**

```
class EventCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'cal/event.html'
    form_class = EventForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(EventCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        selected_date_str = self.request.GET.get('date', None)
        selected_date = datetime.strptime(selected_date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
        kwargs.update({'selected_date': selected_date})
        return kwargs

class EventUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Event
    template_name = 'cal/event.html'
    form_class = EventForm
```

**Template**

```
{% extends 'cal/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}
Event
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="clearfix">
  <a class="btn btn-info left" href="{% url 'cal:calendar' %}"> Calendar </a>
</div>
<div class="container">

<form method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% if form.instance.pk %}
          <h3 class="center">{{ form.instance.start_time }}</h3>
      {% else %}
          <h3 class="center">{{selected_date}}</h3>
      {% endif %}

      <div class="col-4">{{ form.title | as_crispy_field }}</div>
      <div class="col-4">{{ form.description | as_crispy_field }}</div>
      <div class="col-4">{{ form.start_time | as_crispy_field }}</div>
      <div class="col-4">{{ form.end_time | as_crispy_field }}</div>

      {% if form.instance.pk %}
          <a href="{% url 'cal:event_delete' pk=event.pk %}" class="btn btn-danger"> Delete </a>
      {% endif %}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"> Submit </button>

</div>

</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please also post your views.py.

Comment: Just posted the Views. Sorry!

Comment: Try to change the `DateInput` widget to a `DateTimeInput` but keep the same format parameters. See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31944882/785400. Perhaps you have the same problem (you are using `format`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Override the `clean` method to handle creating `datetime` objects
2. I'm pretty sure you need a `DateTimeInput` widget
3. Add a hidden field on your form with the `selected_date`

```py
class EventForm(ModelForm):
    start_time = forms.DateTimeField(required=True, input_formats=['%H:%M'], localize=True, widget=forms.DateTimeInput)
    end_time = forms.DateTimeField(required=True, input_formats=['%H:%M'], localize=True, widget=forms.DateTimeInput)
    selected_date = forms.DateField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'selected_date']

    def __init__(self, selected_date, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['selected_date'].initial = selected_date

    def clean(self):

        end_time = self.cleaned_data['end_time']
        end_time = end_time.replace(year = self.cleaned_data['selected_date'].year)
        end_time = end_time.replace(month = self.cleaned_data['selected_date'].month)
        end_time = end_time.replace(day = self.cleaned_data['selected_date'].day)

        start_time = self.cleaned_data['start_time']
        start_time = start_time.replace(year = self.cleaned_data['selected_date'].year)
        start_time = start_time.replace(month = self.cleaned_data['selected_date'].month)
        start_time = start_time.replace(day = self.cleaned_data['selected_date'].day)

        return self.cleaned_data.update({'end_time': end_time, 'start_time': start_time})
```

To post that `selected_date` to your `EventCreateView` (which happens when the user submits the form from your template), add the following to your template:

```
<form>
...
    <input id="selected_date" type="hidden" name="selected_date" value="{{ selected_date }}">
...
</form>
```

In the same way that the `title` and `description` are automatically extracted from the request and saved to the form, the `selected_date` will be extracted by Django. This happens because the [view you're using automatically gets the POST data](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L44) and [passes it to your form class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L33). Thus, the value of `selected_date` from your `hidden` field will be available to you in your `clean()` method, where we then use it to create the full `datetime` objects and pass them back to the form framework, which will save them for you.

The More on hidden elements can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden).

N.B.: This requires that you pass the `selected_date` back during your POST request, after the user has filled out the `end_time` and `start_time`. This is because Django's form framework will automatically fetch that value if the string matches. (If you need help with that, post your template code.)

My changes rely on the implementation details of Django's forms. The [docs for the `clean` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/) state:

> The form subclass’s clean() method can perform validation that requires access to multiple form fields. This is where you might put in checks such as “if field A is supplied, field B must contain a valid email address”. This method can return a completely different dictionary if it wishes, which will be used as the cleaned_data.

Comment: In your last 2 lines, I'm not sure if you meant: self.fields['end_time'].initial = selected_date.strftime('%H:%M'), because without the strftime, I get TypeError at /event/new/ datetime.datetime' object is not callable. If I use strftime, it works but the date is reverted to a default 1900-01-01 when I save the object.

Comment: Yes, that was a syntax issue in my code. Can you say what you'd expect it to be saved as? Try the updated version of my answer, which includes the `DateTimeInput` widget. The date is being saved in the DB and when you get it back out, the `initial` and the `input_formats` fields we edited in my first version may not affect the rendering to the user. I'm thinking that setting the `format` on the widget may work for those cases when you pull the object back out of the DB.

Comment: I just tried your updated code. It saves the right time, but not the right date. Saves a default date 1900-01-01 instead of selected_date. My hope is for the saved date = selected_date and the time (ie, hours and minutes) to be the one entered by the end user.

Comment: @MaximVallee: Try the latest. I was unclear about your question. Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried your updated code but I'm struggling with the last bit. You mentioned that I had to pass the selected_date back to the POST request. You asked that I post the template, but wouldn't that be in the Views? Should I be overriding the post function under the EventCreateView? I've posted the template anyway. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @MaximVallee: Yes, the template helps. Please see my update. Note (!) that I updated the `fields` attribute on your form. You will need to manually add the `selected_date` in order for this to work. Let me know if this one works. Getting close!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204365/discussion-between-brian-dant-and-maxim-vallee).