# Django calendar form invalid input

Tags: html, django

I currently have this class in form.py

```
class DateForm(forms.Form):
     date = forms.DateTimeField(
     input_formats=['%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'],
     widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={
         'class': 'form-control datetimepicker-input',
         'data-target': '#datetimepicker1'
     }))
```

In my views.py I have this snippet of code where it checks if the form was valid

```
checkout = request.POST.get('place_order')
        if checkout:
            form = DateForm(request.POST)
            print(form)
            if form.is_valid():
                pickup_time = form.cleaned_data['date']
```

However, im getting this error

```
<tr><th><label for="id_date">Date:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>Enter a valid 
date/time.</li></ul><input type="text" name="date" value="04/05/0001 6:07 PM" class="form- 
control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" required id="id_date"></td>. 
</tr>
```

When I submit the form on the webpage im using this format

[image]

Since the formats line up, I'm confused on whether it really is an error with the input method or something bigger.

Comment: What if you use `'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p'` as format?

Comment: Perhaps refer to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944563/change-datetime-input-format-in-django-form could help. ["%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input format is not entirely the same. Indeed, if we parse this with the `datetime` module, we get:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime('04/05/0001 6:07 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 365, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains:  PM
```

So the `PM` part here is not parsed, you can parse that with the `%p` directive, so:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('04/05/0001 6:07 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')
datetime.datetime(1, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

The `input_formats` should thus be:

```
class DateForm(forms.Form):
     date = forms.DateTimeField(
     input_formats=['%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p'],
     widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={
         'class': 'form-control datetimepicker-input',
         'data-target': '#datetimepicker1'
     }))
```

Comment: Thank you so so so very much!